# how to close two mongodb connection with nodes

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Now, i need find "_id" from one db then use this "_id" find data from other db and update first db,but i can't close db connection.

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
  MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var db1 = new Db('test_1', new Server('localhost', 27017));
var db2 = new Db('test_2', new Server('192.68.1.10', 27017));

db1.open(function(error, db1){
  var coll_1 = db1.collection("test_1", {strict:true}, function(error, coll_1){
    coll_1.find().toArray(function(error, items){
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; ++i){
            db2.open(function(error, db2){
                var coll_2 = db2.collection("test_2", {strict:true}, function(error, coll_2){
                    coll_2.find().toArray(function(error, values){
                        coll_1.update(...);     
                    })
                })
                db2.close();
            })  
        }
    })  
    db1.close();
  })
})
```

but the program can't close(),how to do, i can update the data and exit!

Answer (score 2):

Do not create connection for each request like you do. Do create connection to two databases once initially. Then when you initiate first `find` from db1, make a function to count how many items were updated and update that counter every time you update another item from db2. After that counter equals to items from first list, then close database.

Generally you are doing something really weird here, especially with another find and then update in second call. Maybe you need just `update` with `multi: true` argument to update multiple items or similar.

As well, if you need to update second database to exact state as first, consider using mongoexport/mongoimport or mongodump/mongorestore for transporting bulks of data between databases in more efficient ways.